# Scripts not rendering in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view containing two partial views in it.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Expenses";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="expensesreportchart">
            @Html.Action("_SalesAndExpenses", "Reports")
        </div>
<div id="expensesreports">
    @Html.Action("_Expenses", "Reports")
</div>
```

**Note-**

Both partial views are created without using layout. As far as i know that when we use partial views in a view (using layout). Then scripts are obtained in partial views using parent view (the one created with using layout).

So My flow of using partial views in a view is like now-

```
View(using layout)--> partial view(without layout) + partial view(without layout)
```

**Problem-**

I don't get any problem in rendering page.  I mean It renders partial view's layout using `CSS`, But doesn't call scripts from parent view.

**I tried-**

Because Scripts were not working so I had to use scripts again in partial view whether those scripts are used in parent view(the one with layout)

How do i use a partial view so that scripts and everything that i use in parent view should also remain in partial views.

Comment: can you show you partial views?

Comment: as long as your parent view have script, partial view should had no issue with script

Comment: Try using `Html.Partial()` instead.

Comment: @Ballbin, Using `partial` gives me this error- `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CRMaetherius.Models.Sales_Expenses_ReceiptsModel'.`

Comment: You need to make sure you are passing in the model that the partial view is expecting. `@Html.Partial(path to partial view, model);`

Comment: make sure your script is not in document.ready in the partial views

Comment: Yes it is.. My Script like that <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {      my code       }); </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since a partial view isn't loaded when the page loads the scripts on the main page won't trigger for the partial unless you put the functions in a main function that is called after the partial load or you tie the click events to the document

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function(){
    //your code here
});
```

if you have a button on your partial with class="btnSubmit" this code will trigger on the main page when it is clicked